# facebook image url expires now

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am having a single image url like this but it got expired

https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/l/t1.0-9/p180x540/14377_340369866155028_6836158858133154924_n.jpg?oh=7ed0d8818ad54fac851b036d24f5e674&oe=55579EE3

After researching about it I came to know facebook changes the signature url of image for security reason and I found a new method to access the image by passing the user id to this link

> https://graph.facebook.com//picture?width=600

The new method is also expired now. I am looking for solution so that the link of image don';t gets expire.

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with,

**https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/user_id/picture?width=600**

Or according to official documentation of Facebook Graph API, you can make this request using access_token like,

**https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/user_id/picture?width=600&access_token=<access_token>**

Comment: Does the App that generates the Access Token need to be "live" or "verified"?

Comment: yes its working but fb has rate limiting per access_token also